# Best Way to Declare and Define Initialized Const Structs that Reference each Other

Tags: c, struct, constants

There are a number of posts about how to define structures that reference each other, but I don't see one about the variables created with these defined structures.

I have a number of menus that can be navigated in my product that are represented by two structures.  This code builds the structures that I want:

```
typedef void (*MENU_FUNCTION_TYPE)();

typedef enum
{
  MENU_INPUT_NAV,     // Menu just navigates to other menus.
  MENU_INPUT_ACTION,  // Menu displays the results of an action.
  MENU_INPUT_NUM,     // Menu take numeric input and processes it.
  NUM_MENU_INPUTS
} MENU_INPUT_TYPE;

// A menu is comprised of a list of menu items which you select with the number keys.
// This structure defines a menu and the menu items it contains.
struct MENU_ITEM_TYPE;
struct MENU_TYPE
{
  PGM_P text;                         // Pointer to text to display as menu name.
  const MENU_ITEM_TYPE* menu_items;   // Pointer to structures describing each menu item in this menu.
  uint8_t num_items;                  // The number of menu item in this menu.
  MENU_INPUT_TYPE type;               // Specifies how this menu processes keyboard input.
};

// This structure defines a menu item and what it does when you select it.
struct MENU_ITEM_TYPE
{
  PGM_P text;                         // Pointer to text to display as menu item name.
  const MENU_TYPE* link;              // Pointer to which menu selecting this menu item takes you.
  MENU_FUNCTION_TYPE action;          // Pointer to function that is executed when this menu item is selected.
};

extern const MENU_TYPE PROGMEM main_menu;
extern const MENU_TYPE PROGMEM todo_menu;
extern const MENU_TYPE PROGMEM todo2_menu;
extern const MENU_TYPE PROGMEM todo3_menu;
extern const MENU_TYPE PROGMEM todo4_menu;   

// **************************
// "Main Menu"
const char PROGMEM main_menu_text[] = "Main Menu";
const char PROGMEM main_menu_item_text1[] = "First Menu";
const char PROGMEM main_menu_item_text2[] = "Second Menu";
const char PROGMEM main_menu_item_text3[] = "Third Menu";
const char PROGMEM main_menu_item_text4[] = "Fourth Menu";
const MENU_ITEM_TYPE PROGMEM main_menu_items[] =
{
    {main_menu_item_text1, &todo_menu, NULL},
    {main_menu_item_text2, &todo2_menu, NULL},
    {main_menu_item_text3, &todo3_menu, NULL},
    {main_menu_item_text4, &todo4_menu, NULL}
};
const MENU_TYPE PROGMEM main_menu =
{
    main_menu_text,
    main_menu_items,
    LENGTH(main_menu_items, MENU_ITEM_TYPE PROGMEM),
    MENU_INPUT_NAV
};

// **************************
// "TODO Menu"
const char PROGMEM todo_menu_text[] = "TODO Menu";
const char PROGMEM todo_menu_item_text1[] = "todo";
const MENU_ITEM_TYPE PROGMEM todo_menu_items[] =
{
    {todo_menu_item_text1, &todo2_menu, NULL}
};
const MENU_TYPE PROGMEM todo_menu =
{
    todo_menu_text,
    todo_menu_items,
    LENGTH(todo_menu_items, MENU_ITEM_TYPE PROGMEM),
    MENU_INPUT_NAV
};

// **************************
// "TODO2 Menu"
const char PROGMEM todo2_menu_text[] = "TODO2 Menu";
const char PROGMEM todo2_menu_item_text1[] = "todo2";
const MENU_ITEM_TYPE PROGMEM todo2_menu_items[] =
{
    {todo2_menu_item_text1, &todo3_menu, NULL}
};
const MENU_TYPE PROGMEM todo2_menu =
{
    todo2_menu_text,
    todo2_menu_items,
    LENGTH(todo2_menu_items, MENU_ITEM_TYPE PROGMEM),
    MENU_INPUT_NAV
};

// **************************
// "TODO3 Menu"
const char PROGMEM todo3_menu_text[] = "TODO3 Menu";
const char PROGMEM todo3_menu_item_text1[] = "todo3";
const MENU_ITEM_TYPE PROGMEM todo3_menu_items[] =
{
    {todo3_menu_item_text1, &todo4_menu, NULL}
};
const MENU_TYPE PROGMEM todo3_menu =
{
    todo3_menu_text,
    todo3_menu_items,
    LENGTH(todo3_menu_items, MENU_ITEM_TYPE PROGMEM),
    MENU_INPUT_NAV
};

// **************************
// "TODO4 Menu"
const char PROGMEM todo4_menu_text[] = "TODO4 Menu";
const MENU_TYPE PROGMEM todo4_menu =
{
    todo4_menu_text,
    NULL,
    0,
    MENU_INPUT_NUM
};
```

The thing that bugs me about this code is the "extern" keyword.  I need it to compile, but since the structures are defined in the same file it feels there should be a better way to write the code.  I definitely don't want to put all of the declarations in the header file, since none of the code that uses the terminal should ever access these structures directly.  Normally I would get over being bugged and keep coding, but this source is actually going to be seen by customers.

Is there a way I can write this code without the "extern" keywords?

Comment: Do you need all those variable definitions in this header?

Comment: You tagged C++ but this looks like C. In C++ I'd do much more encapsulation than we're seeing here. Bad tag?

Comment: @alk - all of this is in the c file.  None of the data types or structures are needed outside the file.  @ sfjac - I removed the c++.  This is being compiled by avr-gcc in a .cpp file, but the code is intended to be portable to c compilers.

Comment: Your code remains C++ and cannot compile under a pure C compiler, but I don't understand why you need the `extern` keyword. I can post the code corrected that compiles under C and doesn't need the `extern`, but what I am missing? what's the reason for the `extern`?

Comment: @Frankie - if I don't have the extern, then the statement is an uninitialized constant (won't compile due to "error: uninitialized const").

Comment: Using a standard C compiler I don't have the problem. I'll try to post an answer, if it doesn't works for you I'll remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In standard C a struct is not equivalent to a `typedef`.
This amended code compiles on a standard C compiler:

```
typedef void (*MENU_FUNCTION_TYPE)();

typedef enum
{
  MENU_INPUT_NAV,     // Menu just navigates to other menus.
  MENU_INPUT_ACTION,  // Menu displays the results of an action.
  MENU_INPUT_NUM,     // Menu take numeric input and processes it.
  NUM_MENU_INPUTS
} MENU_INPUT_TYPE;

// A menu is comprised of a list of menu items which you select with the number keys.
// This structure defines a menu and the menu items it contains.
typedef struct tag_MENU_ITEM_TYPE MENU_ITEM_TYPE;
typedef struct tag_MENU_TYPE
{
  PGM_P text;                         // Pointer to text to display as menu name.
  const MENU_ITEM_TYPE* menu_items;   // Pointer to structures describing each menu item in this menu.
  uint8_t num_items;                  // The number of menu item in this menu.
  MENU_INPUT_TYPE type;               // Specifies how this menu processes keyboard input.
} MENU_TYPE;

// This structure defines a menu item and what it does when you select it.
typedef struct tag_MENU_ITEM_TYPE
{
  PGM_P text;                         // Pointer to text to display as menu item name.
  const MENU_TYPE* link;              // Pointer to which menu selecting this menu item takes you.
  MENU_FUNCTION_TYPE action;          // Pointer to function that is executed when this menu item is selected.
} MENU_ITEM_TYPE;

//These now acts as forward declarations
const MENU_TYPE PROGMEM main_menu;
const MENU_TYPE PROGMEM todo_menu;
const MENU_TYPE PROGMEM todo2_menu;
const MENU_TYPE PROGMEM todo3_menu;
const MENU_TYPE PROGMEM todo4_menu;   

// **************************
// "Main Menu"
const char PROGMEM main_menu_text[] = "Main Menu";
const char PROGMEM main_menu_item_text1[] = "First Menu";
const char PROGMEM main_menu_item_text2[] = "Second Menu";
const char PROGMEM main_menu_item_text3[] = "Third Menu";
const char PROGMEM main_menu_item_text4[] = "Fourth Menu";
const MENU_ITEM_TYPE PROGMEM main_menu_items[] =
{
    {main_menu_item_text1, &todo_menu, NULL},
    {main_menu_item_text2, &todo2_menu, NULL},
    {main_menu_item_text3, &todo3_menu, NULL},
    {main_menu_item_text4, &todo4_menu, NULL}
};
const MENU_TYPE PROGMEM main_menu =
{
    main_menu_text,
    main_menu_items,
    LENGTH(main_menu_items, MENU_ITEM_TYPE PROGMEM),
    MENU_INPUT_NAV
};

// **************************
// "TODO Menu"
const char PROGMEM todo_menu_text[] = "TODO Menu";
const char PROGMEM todo_menu_item_text1[] = "todo";
const MENU_ITEM_TYPE PROGMEM todo_menu_items[] =
{
    {todo_menu_item_text1, &todo2_menu, NULL}
};
const MENU_TYPE PROGMEM todo_menu =
{
    todo_menu_text,
    todo_menu_items,
    LENGTH(todo_menu_items, MENU_ITEM_TYPE PROGMEM),
    MENU_INPUT_NAV
};

// **************************
// "TODO2 Menu"
const char PROGMEM todo2_menu_text[] = "TODO2 Menu";
const char PROGMEM todo2_menu_item_text1[] = "todo2";
const MENU_ITEM_TYPE PROGMEM todo2_menu_items[] =
{
    {todo2_menu_item_text1, &todo3_menu, NULL}
};
const MENU_TYPE PROGMEM todo2_menu =
{
    todo2_menu_text,
    todo2_menu_items,
    LENGTH(todo2_menu_items, MENU_ITEM_TYPE PROGMEM),
    MENU_INPUT_NAV
};

// **************************
// "TODO3 Menu"
const char PROGMEM todo3_menu_text[] = "TODO3 Menu";
const char PROGMEM todo3_menu_item_text1[] = "todo3";
const MENU_ITEM_TYPE PROGMEM todo3_menu_items[] =
{
    {todo3_menu_item_text1, &todo4_menu, NULL}
};
const MENU_TYPE PROGMEM todo3_menu =
{
    todo3_menu_text,
    todo3_menu_items,
    LENGTH(todo3_menu_items, MENU_ITEM_TYPE PROGMEM),
    MENU_INPUT_NAV
};

// **************************
// "TODO4 Menu"
const char PROGMEM todo4_menu_text[] = "TODO4 Menu";
const MENU_TYPE PROGMEM todo4_menu =
{
    todo4_menu_text,
    NULL,
    0,
    MENU_INPUT_NUM
};
```

Comment: It still doesn't compile for me with avr-gcc (version that came with Arduino 1.6.4), because I get the "uninitialized const" error I described before.  I tried it in microchip's XC8, however, and it built although it did give me the warning "newmain.c:74: warning: (1478) initial value for "_main_menu" differs to that in newmain.c:52" for each of the structures.  Even though it seems like I can't get rid of the "extern" with avr-gcc, I'm selecting this as the correct answer since I'll be adopting your changes with the typedefs.

Comment: It compiles well in C99 and C11, which standard is AVR-GCC? Maybe you can mask the `extern` under a `#define FWD_DECLARE extern` to make it more acceptable? Not a real solution, more a makup :( Anyway the typedef is absolutely necessary to compile under plain C.

Comment: Yup, your typedef was the right thing for me to do.  The FWD_DECLARE macro is a good idea too.  Thank.

Answer (score 0):

If this is user-visible code, and you wish it to compile without errors or warnings using `avr-gcc -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra` and `avr-g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra` (plus whatever `-O` and `-mmcu=` etc. options you need), I suggest you hide the fragile parts in macros, and make the macros robust. For example, using structures that closely match the ones shown in the original question:

```
#include <avr/pgmspace.h>
#define JOIN2TOKENS(token1, token2)  JOIN2TOKENS_(token1, token2)
#define JOIN2TOKENS_(token1, token2) token1 ## token2

struct menu_st {
    const char                      *const title;
    unsigned char                    const items;
    const struct menuitem_st *const *const item;
};

struct menuitem_st {
    const char                      *const label;
    void                           (*const action)();
    const struct menu_st            *const submenu;
};

#define DECLARE_MENU(name, titlestr) \
    extern const struct menu_st name PROGMEM; \
    static const PROGMEM char JOIN2TOKENS(title_of__, name) [] PROGMEM = titlestr

#define DECLARE_MENUITEM(name, labelstr, funcptr, menuptr) \
    static const char JOIN2TOKENS(label_of__, name) [] PROGMEM = labelstr; \
    static const struct menuitem_st name [1] PROGMEM = { { JOIN2TOKENS(label_of__, name), funcptr, menuptr } }

#define DECLARE_SUBMENU(name, labelstr, tomenu) \
    DECLARE_MENUITEM(name, labelstr, (void (*)())0, &(tomenu))

#define DECLARE_ACTION(name, labelstr, funcname) \
    DECLARE_MENUITEM(name, labelstr, funcname, (const struct menu_st *const )0)

#define DECLARE_ACTSUB(name, labelstr, funcname, tomenu) \
    DECLARE_MENUITEM(name, labelstr, funcname, &(tomenu))

#define DEFINE_MENU(name, ...) \
    static const struct menuitem_st *const JOIN2TOKENS(menu_items_of__, name) [] PROGMEM = { __VA_ARGS__ }; \
    const struct menu_st name PROGMEM = { \
        JOIN2TOKENS(title_of__, name), \
        sizeof (JOIN2TOKENS(menu_items_of__, name)) / sizeof (JOIN2TOKENS(menu_items_of__, name)[0]), \
        JOIN2TOKENS(menu_items_of__, name), \
    }


/* 0. Declare or define menu action functions.
 *    These are declared as static, so that they are only visible
 *    in the current compilation unit.
 *
 *    As an example, action_1() and action_2() are defined here,
 *    but defaults() is only declared.
*/
static void action_1(void) { return; }
static void action_2(void) { return; }
static void defaults(void);

/* 1. Declare each menu.
 *
 *    DECLARE_MENU(name, string)
 *        'name' is the menu variable name, and
 *        'string' is the menu title, a string literal.
*/
DECLARE_MENU(main_menu, "Main menu");
DECLARE_MENU(submenu_1, "First submenu");
DECLARE_MENU(submenu_2, "Second submenu");

/* 2. Declare each menu item. Below,
 *        'name' is the local variable name (used in DEFINE_MENU()),
 *        'string' is the text for this menu item,
 *        'function' is the function called when the menu item is activated, and
 *        'menu' is the name of the menu the menu item takes to.
 *
 *    DECLARE_SUBMENU(name, string, menu)
 *        Declare a menu item, that takes to another menu.
 *
 *    DECLARE_ACTION(name, string, function)
 *        Declare a menu item, that causes a function to be called.
 *
 *    DECLARE_ABTSUB(name, string, function, menu)
 *        Declare a menu item, that causes a function to be called,
 *        and then changes to another menu.
 *
*/
DECLARE_SUBMENU(to_main_menu, "Back to main menu", main_menu);
DECLARE_SUBMENU(to_submenu_1, "To first submenu",  submenu_1);
DECLARE_SUBMENU(to_submenu_2, "To second submenu", submenu_2);
DECLARE_ACTION(do_action_1,   "Action 1", action_1);
DECLARE_ACTION(do_action_2,   "Action 2", action_2);
DECLARE_ACTSUB(do_defaults,   "Reset to defaults", defaults, main_menu);

/* 3. Define which menus have which menu items.
 *
 *    DEFINE_MENU(name, menu_item_1 [, ..., menu_item_N ])
 *        'name' is the menu variable name, and should have been
 *               declared using DECLARE_MENU(name, string) before.
 *        'menu_item_1' (and all additional parameters) are
 *               menu items declared before using
 *               DECLARE_SUBMENU(), DECLARE_ACTION(), or DECLARE_ACTSUB().
*/    
DEFINE_MENU(main_menu, to_submenu_1, to_submenu_2);
DEFINE_MENU(submenu_1, to_submenu_2, do_action_1, do_action_2, to_main_menu);
DEFINE_MENU(submenu_2, to_submenu_1, do_defaults, to_main_menu);

/* 4. If the menu action functions were only declared earlier,
 *    define them here.
*/
static void defaults(void) { return; }
```

The `DECLARE_MENU()` macro does use `extern const`, to forward-declare the menu structures. Only the menu names -- `main_menu`, `submenu_1`, and `submenu_2`, above -- are externally visible. This happens to work correctly in both C99 and C++11. If you wish the symbols to be local, you'll need different code for C99 and for C++11 (doable, via `#ifdef __cplusplus` - `#else` - `#endif`, but ugly, if you ask me).

Both `avr-gcc-4.8.2 -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra` and `avr-g++-4.8.2 -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra` store all the data structures in `.progmem.data` section.

Note that because GCC does not support multiple address spaces (last I checked was avr-gcc-4.8.2), you'll have to use `pgm_read_byte()` and `pgm_read_word()` macros defined in `<avr/pgmspace.h>` to access the data structures. For example, instead of `main_menu.items` you'll need to use `pgm_read_byte(&(main_menu.items))`. Something like the following example -- but note that this part is untested, and might contain typos/thinkos, especially regarding dereferencing the pointers:

```
extern void print_clear_all(void);
extern void print_menu_title(const char *const pgm_string);
extern void print_menu_item(const char *const pgm_string, const unsigned char is_focus);
extern void print_clear_rest();

static const menu_t *current_menu = &main_menu;
static unsigned char current_item = 0;

void menu_refresh(void)
{
    const unsigned char n = pgm_read_byte(&(current_menu->items));
    const void *const *const itemarray = (const void *const *)pgm_read_word(&(current_menu->item));
    unsigned char i;
    print_clear_all();
    print_menu_title((const char *)pgm_read_word(&(current_menu->title)));
    for (i = 0U; i < n; i++)
        print_menu_item((const char *)pgm_read_word(itemarray + i), i == current_item);
    print_clear_rest();
}

void menu_prev(void)
{
    if (current_item > 0U)
        --current_item;
    menu_refresh();
}

void menu_next(void)
{
    if (current_item + 1U < pgm_read_byte(&(current_menu->items)))
        ++current_item;
    menu_refresh();
}

void menu_enter(void)
{
    const void *const *const itemarray = (const void *const *const)pgm_read_word(&(current_menu->item));
    const menuitem_t *const item = (const menuitem_t *const)pgm_read_word(itemarray + current_item);
    void (*const action)() = (void (*)())pgm_read_word(&(item->action));
    const menu_t *const submenu = (const menu_t *const)pgm_read_word(&(item->submenu));
    if (action)
        action();
    if (submenu)
        current_menu = submenu;
    menu_refresh();
}
```

It seems to me that using pointers makes the code pretty dense. A completely different approach, one that would use an array index to identify the menu, and another to identify the option, seems much more preferable to me.